# Audits mess up on migrated questions

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, migrated-questions

Well, I was reviewing in the Close Vote queue earlier when I hit this strange review task:

[image]

There's no review buttons except for skip. So I looked at [the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51251/processing-text-files-for-data-extraction-and-analysis). Apparently, it was migrated to Code Review. I'm not sure why it was chosen as a review audit... but something's not right here.

Comment: [You're not the only one.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255618/in-what-cases-do-the-buttons-disappear-in-reviews) Reiterated from there: the buttons do show up for moderators. Based on the votes, though, I imagine it was chosen as a "Leave Open" audit, even though it's closed.

Comment: Tired of this audit popping up and confusing people so I just completed it. Hopefully it doesn't get selected again.