# Nearly impossible late answer audit

Tags: bug, review-audits, late-answers

So, I got this late answer audit ([link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/84939)).  It is based on [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/264057/40980) deleted answer.

Note that it can't be flagged, voted on, or commented on.  This is likely because the question it is part of is *also* a locked question.  The "I'm done" button successfully completes the audit.

Answers where there is no way to act upon it (impossible to vote, flag, or comment) *shouldn't* be selected for audits. It increases the likelihood of "what should I do?" which can have adverse consequences for the reviewer.

The audit:

[image]

The answer (note inability to flag there because its locked):

[image]

Side note: this can have other possible bad audits in the event of an answer being deleted because of a rejected migration where the answer originated on the other site.

Comment: Partially related: [Audits mess up on migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231964/audits-mess-up-on-migrated-questions) (you mentioned rejected migrations, this is about migrations on the source site, in which the question is locked after migration)

Comment: @ShadowLizard, as such?