# Late answer review audit on a locked question does not give me any options

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

[Review audit](https://serverfault.com/review/late-answers/239979) gave me answer, without any possibility to do anything else than "No action needed" or "Skip" (see attached image). There is no way to vote, no way to comment, no way to flag.

[image: Late Answers review]

The reason is probably that the question is locked. Is it expected, that we should *Skip* such answers, even when we see that the answer is obviously "bad"? Clicking on the *No action needed*  leads to obvious **STOP and listen** warning.

I am not writing to complain, but reporting behaviour that is not correct and hope it will get fixed (I hope this way is appropriate to report such bugs here).

Comment: Heh... Answers to Historical Lock questions are not actually locked themselves (although the UI treats them that way) - so the check to exclude locked posts from audits misses this. Oops...

Comment: Similar to [Audits mess up on migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231964/audits-mess-up-on-migrated-questions)

Comment: @Shog9 What is the state of this? It didn't happen to me anymore, but I am wondering if it is handled, working on, or forgotten.

Comment: We'll fix it eventually; this is vanishingly rare though. Arguably, HL should never be used on questions that new, which just leaves new answers to old questions - less rare, but still very rare.